# Arnold's Trivium: Problem 5

Tags: proof-verification, recreational-mathematics

For fun and for the challenge, I'm trying to solve a few of Arnold's problems. I did Problem 5 and I would like to check if my solution is correct.

> **Problem 5:** Calculate the $100$th derivative of the function $$\frac{1}{x^2+3x+2}$$ at $x=0$ with $10\%$ relative error.

**Spoiler alert: my solution below. If you want to attempt solving the trivium some day, don't read ahead.**

*Solution:* We have
$$\frac{1}{x^2+3x+2} = \frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)} = \frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{x+2}\ .$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{d^{100}}{dx^{100}}\frac{1}{x^2+3x+2} = 100!\left(\frac{1}{(x+1)^{101}}-\frac{1}{(x+2)^{101}}\right)\ .$$
At $x=0$, this gives
$$100!\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{101}}\right)\approx\sqrt{200\pi}\left(\frac{100}{e}\right)^{100}\approx 25\left(\frac{100}{e}\right)^{100}$$
where we used Stirling's approximation and the approximations
$$1-\frac{1}{2^{100}}\approx 1\ ,\qquad \sqrt{200\pi}\approx 25\ .$$

I believe this to be correct. Is it enough though, or do we need a numerical value at the end (which would be pretty hard to obtain without a computer...)? Are there other ways to obtain a solution?

Comment: having worked through a few of these, I really don't think he meant for us to obtain exactly what you got (i.e. a rough approximation of the exact numerical answer).

Comment: You are missing proving that your approximation is close to the real value the magnitude required.

Comment: Fair enough, but Stirling is very good at such big numbers, and $1-2^{-100}\approx1$ is also basically exact. So I'm just missing the approximation for $\sqrt{200\pi}$, which is easy (also remark that I could leave it without approximating...)

Comment: I would stay with the $\sqrt{200\pi}$ term since, in any manner, you will need a calculator to get $\left(\frac{100}{e}\right)^{100}$. Using them, you would get $\approx 9.32485\times 10^{157}$ for an "exact" value  $\approx 9.33262\times 10^{157}$ while the other shortcut would give   $\approx 9.30019\times 10^{157}$

Answer (score 0):

$$f (x)=\frac {1}{1+x}-\frac {1}{2+x}$$

$$=1-x+x^2-...+(-1)^nx^n-$$
$$1/2 (1-x/2+x^2/4-...+(-1)^nx^n/2^n+$$
$$x^n\epsilon (x) $$

$$\implies f^{(100)}(0)=100!(1-\frac {1}{2^{101}}) $$

Comment: Sure, but it's basically the same as my answer (with the difference that I get the derivative at any point, while you can only do Taylor for $|x|<1$)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud No, Taylor finite expansion is valide for all $x $ not only those satisfying $|x|<1$. That is power series expansion. also we have $|0|<1$.

Comment: Ah, right. But doesn't the approximation get pretty bad as you go away from $0$? (Not that it matters for the specific problem, but still.)

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud But it gives you the exact derivative.